# Prevent Iron:Router from processing hashbang urls

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a site in meteor with Iron:router.  Google thinks that my site has several #! urls that are valid and is displaying them in our results (simply urls that end #!).  Iron Router is routing all of these to '/' How do I get it to not do so?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Having the same issue, can't share to linkedin without a hashbang or it wont show pictures but add the hashbang and it reroutes to / :( @lassombra

Comment: @PhilipPryde unfortunately I ended up hacking iron:location to handle this.  I've since moved to flow router which by default ignores #! urls.  iron:router is just very opinionated.

Comment: I thought I would end up in there I had to do something like that before. Maybe it's worth a pull request. Causes havoc with app cache or used to aswell